# MemoryStream output to a file c#

Tags: c#, filestream, streamwriter, memorystream

I have below code:

```
string fileName = GetFileName();
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {            
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(String.Format("{0};{1};{2};{3};{4};{5}", i.ToString(), (i*2).ToString(), "-_-_-", "-_" + i.ToString() + "_-", "3", "15"));
        }

        // Check if compression needed.
        if (stream.Length > limit)
        {
            sw.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            using (Ionic.Zip.ZipFile zipFile = new Ionic.Zip.ZipFile())
            {
                absoluteFileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
                zipFile.AddEntry(absoluteFileName, stream);

                zipFileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName), Path.ChangeExtension(absoluteFileName, ZipExtension));
                zipFile.Save(zipFileName);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // no compression needed
            using (FileStream file = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);
                file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                //stream.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to generate a plain text file in case memorystream length (in bytes) is no greater than a concrete amount of bytes (limit (see conditional).

If memorystream length is greater than a concrete amount of bytes then I create a zipped file.

My problem is in the else body when I try to write all the content of memory stream into a plain text file when no need to compress (stream.Length <= limit). I get a file of 39bytes but when I open it, it is empty, only new lines within it.

I do this because I do not want to create the file on disk directly in case I need to compress it. So if at the end no need to compress, I write all the streammemory to a file and that is the problem, file is empty, only newlines.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE2**
I have put below line just before conditional:

```
 sw.Flush();
 stream.Position = 0;
```

And now the content is written to file.

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code in future. I've done it for you this time, but it's really your responsibility to make the code as readable as possible. Use the preview and ask yourself whether that's really how you'd want to read the code.

Comment: @JonSkeet ok, thanks.

Comment: Where is the `stream.Position = 0;` in the `else` branch?

Comment: when Jon is here no fear, u definitely get solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My problem is in the else body

Well you're handling that in a different way to in the first `if` body.

In the first `if` body, you're explicitly flushing the writer and rewinding the stream:

```
sw.Flush();
stream.Position = 0;
```

You're not doing either of those in the `else` body, so you won't get any data that's already been written to the stream (no rewind) and there could still be data buffered in the `StreamWriter` (no flush). That's *one* problem.

Next, you're checking your "limit" without flushing the `StreamWriter`, which means there could be a bunch more data meaning you *should* compress, but you're not. So I suggest you call `sw.Flush()` before your `if` statement occurs at all.

Finally, I'd strongly recommend against creating another byte array for no reason - the body of your final `using` statement can just be:

```
stream.CopyTo(file);
```

Comment: No CopyTo method appears on stream, I am using .NET Framework 3.5 under Visual Studio 2008. It is only available from .NET Framework 4.0 and later.

Comment: @user1624552: It would have been useful if you'd said that - I think it's reasonable that most people assume you're not constrained to a framework released nearly 10 years ago... you still don't need to create another byte array though. You could use `MemoryStream.GetBuffer()` instead, for example.

Comment: I agree, very sorry. And a lot of thanks, you save my day!